# Why does MDN suggest using initial-scale=0.86 and minimum-scale=0.86 in viewport tag to suppress horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport

I've been revisiting the viewport tag on MDN and in article [Viewport width and screen width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag#viewport_width_and_screen_width), they suggest:

> Suppress the **small zoom applied by many smartphones** by setting the initial scale and minimum-scale values to 0.86. The result is horizontal scroll is suppressed in any orientation and the user can zoom in if they want to.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.86"
```

The MDN page was last modified on Jul 27, 2021. I've always used `initial-scale:1` for my work and have never come across any mobile device which applies zoom to it.

1. Are there really many smartphones that apply zoom? If yes, please give a few examples.
2. Where does the number `0.86` come from? Any references?

Comment: I even went through the history of changes for this MDN page here https://github.com/mdn/content/commits/main/files/en-us/web/html/viewport_meta_tag/index.html
and could not find a commit associated with this text. You can try to post an issue on Github to get more information and hopefully someone there can provide more information

Answer (score 3):

I will focus on the references part.

This is the PR: https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/612

Author and description:

[image]

Changes can be found at https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/612/files

A glance:

[image]

The commit: https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/612/commits/0e98d81de11f8c8b07e3936e54b708b91aa8757f